# Summing up row values in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have data of this type in matlab

```
1 1 10
1 2 10
1 2 3
2 1 1
2 1 25
2 3 4
```

From the above dataset I want something like this

```
1 1 10
1 2 13
2 1 26
2 3 4
```

basically sum the counts. How can I do it efficiently in matlab?

My actual data

```
     1653082       94751           1
     1653082      133609           1
     1653082       15712           1
     1653082       15712           1
     1653082       15712           1
     1653082       87905          22
```

Comment: "Sum the counts"? Could you explain better?

Comment: @LuisMendo. Yes sum up the counts which is basically the third column

Answer (score 1):

The usual combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can do the job:

```
data = [1653082       94751           1
        1653082      133609           1
        1653082       15712           1
        1653082       15712           1
        1653082       15712           1
        1653082       87905          22];

[ii, ~, kk] = unique(data(:,1:2),'rows');
vv = accumarray(kk, data(:,3));
result = [ ii vv ];
```

The result in this example is:

```
result =
     1653082       15712           3
     1653082       87905          22
     1653082       94751           1
     1653082      133609           1
```

Comment: I tried your method on my actual data shown in the question and it shows out of memory issue?

Comment: @user34790 Well... if your data is very large, I guess that can happen

Comment: Any solution, how I can overcome it. For eg in the specific data I gave in the question

Comment: @user34790 Oh, I see: you have much higher values in first two rows than there were in your original example; that's what's causing the problem. Please see edited answer

Comment: @user34790 Using `unique` is a good workaround, but `accumarray` has a sparse matrix output option that is [nicely suited to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21791422/2778484).  :)

Answer (score 1):

The [sparse output option of `accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#f78-1048777) solves these memory issues, and obviates the need for `unique`.  Using the actual data from bottom of the question:

```
>> R = accumarray(data(:,1:2),data(:,3),[],@sum,0,true)
R =
            (1653082,15712)                   3
            (1653082,87905)                  22
            (1653082,94751)                   1
            (1653082,133609)                  1
>> [ii,jj] = find(R);
>> M = [ii jj nonzeros(R)]
M =
     1653082       15712           3
     1653082       87905          22
     1653082       94751           1
     1653082      133609           1
```

Comment: You can directly use `R = sparse(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3));`. `sparse` does an implicit `accumarray`

Comment: That's true. Floris keeps reminding me of that option... and I keep forgetting.  :)

Comment: Or even `spconvert(data)`! Just found out about that function

Comment: That one I didn't know about!